# dynamic progress bar from textbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, input

Working on a site for my Pen and Paper style RPG and i want to be able to update the health bars on the fly. Been looking around and found some stuff to update a progess bar by check boxes but not text boxes and i just cant figure out how to do it. Ideally id also like to make the progress bar a custom design but right now i just want to get it to work.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="generator" content="CoffeeCup HTML Editor (www.coffeecup.com)">
    <meta name="dcterms.created" content="Tue, 12 Mar 2019 18:08:09 GMT">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <title>Health</title>

    <!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <style>
    .tasks{
    background-color: #F6F8F8;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.tasks span{
    font-weight: bold;
}
.tasks input{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.tasks a{
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    border:none;
}
.tasks a:hover{
    border-bottom: dashed 1px #0088cc;
}
.tasks label{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
        </div>
    </div>
    <input name="done" class="done" type="textbox" id="txtJob" value="99">

      <script>
  var valeur = document.getElementsByName('txtJob')[0].value
  $('.progress-bar').css('width', valeur+'%').attr('aria-valuenow', valeur);    
//});
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've got most of it. You're just left with initialization and event binding.

```
// Create function for updating the progress bar
function update(target) {
  var valeur = $(target).val();
  $('.progress-bar').css('width', valeur+'%').attr('aria-valuenow', valeur);
}

// Use that function to initialize the progress bar
update($('#txtJob'));

// Add event handlers so that changes to the textbox update the progress bar
$('#txtJob').on('change keyup', event => update(event.currentTarget));
```

Comment: that did it thanks. I need to tinker with it a boit more since not everyone is going to have 100 HP, but thats easy i just need to basically  take the value in #txtJob devide by the players max hp and that should produce the percent to update, but thats the easy part!
thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a few questions I have regarding the goal. Are you wanting only one text box to determine the length of the progress bar? And if so, is that length based on someone entering digits 0-100?

If that is your goal, then you are almost there. I would move a few things around and model the code like this. First I imported a more up-todate version of jQuery.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then I updated the HTML markup to include the classes mentioned in the CSS and updated the javascript to use jQuery, since you had imported it already, we should use it :)

```
<body class="tasks">
    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
        </div>
    </div>
    <input name="done" class="done" type="textbox" id="txtJob" value="0">

    <script>

        $(function () {
            $('#txtJob').keyup(function(){
                var valeur = $('#txtJob').val();
                $('.progress-bar').css('width', valeur+'%').attr('aria-valuenow', valeur);  
            });
        });  

    </script>

</body>
```